# Python import error thrown when Renderman for Blender addon is enabled

Tags: python, blender, renderman

I recently installed Renderman with the respective Blender addon. At first, it threw no errors, but rendered a blank screen whenever I tried to use it, so I reinstalled everything.
When I went through the whole installation process again (downloading Renderman-InstallerNCR-version, running it and installing Renderman, restarting my computer, downloading the addon zip and adding it in Blender through preferences), and tried to enable the Renderman Blender addon, these errors popped up in a Blender text window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Pixar\RendermanProServer-24.0\bin\rman-utils\rman-assets\common\shading-node.py", line 14, in <module> import oslquery as oslq
...
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _oslquery: The specified module could not be found.
```

The full error image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7N3i.png), the second error is the same as the first.

First I looked for oslquery and _oslquery in Pixar\RendermanProServer... and I found that the files that failed to import were in multiple places throughout the bin and library, so they aren't missing.
Then I looked up oslquery on google, and got to the main [github page](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenShadingLanguage) for open shader language. It looks like Renderman uses OSL for some functionality, but is having trouble getting OSL to communicate with its python components.

I haven't seen my specific errors anywhere online.
I have validated the install of every component of Renderman and the Rm Blender addon.

Does anybody know how I could get Renderman working? I'm going to try reinstalling again soon, bc sometimes computers just work like that.

Update:
I did some extra digging, here is some excerpts of the files throwing the first error is this:
...\common\shading_node.py:

```
try:
    import oslquery as oslq
except:
    import oslquery as oslq
```

When I get rid of this line, a different import error is thrown:

```
DLL load failed while importing _Ctx: The specified module could no be found.
```

From this, I have determined the issue is one of two things:
file path error: unlikely because I modified the python files try to import to just check if they knew their files were there and it worked.
file type errer: maybe, is there any difference between .dll and .pyd?

_oslquery is a "Python Extension File" in the same directory and is causing an ImportError when imported. _oslquery cannot be read as text and is much larger that the other two files, it's file extension is .pyd

So basically, I think that the python file is looking for a dll and not finding it, but I do not know if that is correct or how to fix that. So I'm just going to reinstall again and check back tomorrow.

Comment: Not an expert on Renderman, but you may need to add one or more of the relevant paths to the %PATH% environment variable. Alternatively, you can do sys.path.append() at runtime (you would put the append statement BEFORE the import statement)

Comment: Renderman has it's own system environment variable RMANTREE, I'll take a look at it later. Restarting your computer is supposed to set it  correctly but I haven't checked it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled and it turned on without errors, and now I'm back to the issue where everything renders out grey and materials don't work.
I'm just going to use Cycles X lmao, but its weird that nobody else is having that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just signed up today-

So I had the exact same problem, don't know if it was a internet quality issue or what-

I got it working on 2.83 and it seems that they also mentioned that on the RM community somewhere. Seems its not happy with 2.93. Can this get flagged as an low severity issue?